# com.google.mlkit.nl.translate.Translation.getClient , is imported but getClient isient working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, translators

com.google.mlkit.nl.translate.Translation.getClient
[Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG33V.jpg)

In Above Image i have Imported the getClient() but it agai it shows me to import

Comment: Using this Code may Fix  the Error  

    val englishGermanTranslator = Translation.getClient(options)

Answer (score 0):

I just faced with this issue too, for a temporary time you can use Firebase Natural Language library. [Document Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/translate-text),

First in your grandle file insert this -

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language-translate-model:20.0.8'
```

For the translation model -

```
val options = FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
    .setSourceLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.DE)
    .setTargetLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.TR)
    .build()
val englishGermanTranslator =  FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options)


englishGermanTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        // Model downloaded successfully. Okay to start translating.
        // (Set a flag, unhide the translation UI, etc.)
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        // Model couldn’t be downloaded or other internal error.
        // ...
    }
englishGermanTranslator.translate(text)
    .addOnSuccessListener { translatedText ->
        Log.d("translate","done \t $translatedText")
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
         // Error.
         // ...
    }
```

I Hope it will be help to you